# Button images in tableviewcell do not show any change

Tags: swift3, uibutton

```
import UIKit

``class SelectOptionsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var Radiobutton: UIButton!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    Radiobutton.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "Radio OFF.jpg"), for: .normal)
    Radiobutton.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "Radio ON.jpg"), for: .selected)

}


@IBAction func RadioButton(_ sender: Any) {
    print("buttonClicked")
   // Radiobutton.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "Radio ON.jpg"), for: .selected)

}
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

I am trying to change button images in `tableviewcell`. When I click the button it shows radio on images and when I click the next cell, the button images shows radio button and when button in normal state it shows radio off button.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the code for setting image on button click

```
@IBAction func RadioButton(_ sender: Any) { 

sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected

if sender.isSelected 
{

 Radiobutton.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "Radio ON.jpg"), for: .selected)
}

else
{

  Radiobutton.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "Radio OFF.jpg"), for: .normal)

  }

}
```